# How can I exit a while(1) based on a user input?

Tags: c, while-loop, break

I have a simple `server-client` terminals. The server receives strings from the client and processes it. The server will only start processing once it receives the `end_of_input` character which in my case is `'&'`. The while loop below is meant to allow a user to input a number of different strings and should stop performing as it receives `'&'`.

```
while(1) {
    printf("Enter string to process: ");
    scanf("%s", client_string);

    string_size=strlen(client_string);
    //I want to escape here if client_string ends with '&'
    write(csd, client_string, string_size);
}
```

How could I make it so that the while loop exits after a user inputs the `end_of_input` character `'&'`?

Comment: use `break;`....

Comment: @SouravGhosh i tried using if (client_string[string_size] == '&') break; with no luck

Comment: Better even, `while ( client_string[ string_size - 1 ] != '&' )` with some re-arranging of the loop innards...

Comment: @Drgabble in `C` `while(1)` is preferable. You're thinking in `java-way`.

Comment: @xenteros Ah my apologies, I thought it was C++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while(1) {
    printf("Enter string to process: ");
    scanf("%s", client_string);

    string_size=strlen(client_string);
    write(csd, client_string, string_size);
    if (client_string[string_size -1 ] == '&') {
        break;
    }
}
```

`break` keyword can be used for immediate stopping and escaping the loop. It is used in most of programming languages.
There is also one useful keyword to slightly influence loop processing: `continue`. It immediately jumps to the next iteration.

**Examples**:

```
int i = 0;
while (1) {
    if (i == 4) {
        break;
    }
    printf("%d\n", i++);
}
```

will print:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Continue:

```
int i = 0;
while (1) {
    if (i == 4) {
        continue;
    }
    if (i == 6) {
        break;
    }
    printf("%d\n", i++);
}
```

will print:

```
0
1
2
3
5
```

Comment: I tried using: if (client_string[string_size] == '&') break; with no luck

Comment: use if (client_string[string_size -1 ] == '&') break;

Comment: @nanjeroechizen it's because if you have n letters in an array, nth one will have index n-1. Please mark the answer as a solution :)

Comment: So what would happen is the user just hit the enter-key, without any additional input?

Comment: @alk - scanf waits for a not empty string.

Comment: Ok, then I'd press Ctrl-D next. ;->

Comment: @alk when you go to self-cash-desk at a supermarked, would you type 2147483648 plastic bags just to see what happens? :p

Comment: Me? Yes, sure! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just drop this `while(1)` statement. You want to happen the scanning at least once, so use a `do-while()` construct instead:

```
#define END_OF_INPUT '&'

...


do 
{
  printf("Enter string to process: \n");
  scanf("%s", client_string);

  string_size = strlen(client_string);
  write(csd, client_string, string_size);
} while ((string_size > 0) && /* Take care to not run into doing client_string[0 - 1] */
         (client_string[string_size - 1] != END_OF_INPUT));
```

In case the stopper should not be sent:

```
int end_of_input = 0;

do 
{
  printf("Enter string to process: \n");
  scanf("%s", client_string);

  string_size = strlen(client_string);

  end_of_input = (string_size > 0) && (client_string[string_size - 1] == END_OF_INPUT);
  if (end_of_input)
  {
    client_string[string_size - 1] = `\0`;
  }

  write(csd, client_string, string_size);
} while (!end_of_input);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(1) {
    printf("Enter string to process: ");
    scanf("%s", client_string);

    string_size=strlen(client_string);

    if (client_string[string_size - 1] == '&')
        break;
    write(csd, client_string, string_size);
}
```

- break keyword can be used for immediate stopping and escaping the loop.

Comment: This would break on any `&` not matter where in the string input.

Comment: @xenteros how you are telling?