# Programming in C, ending a while loop

Tags: c

I am new to C and I found 1 forum in C for ending a while loop and that one did not really help as with the break it still does not work. It gives me a "expected ; before break" or "int keep_playing=4" to end the loop. This is a simple rock paper scissors game and I am just working on the loop and going to soon worry about the logic portion. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Welcome to rock paper scissors!\n");
    int keep_playing=5;
    while (keep_playing==5)
        printf("Press 'y' to play or 'n' to quit: ");
        char playornot;
        scanf("%c\n",&playornot);
        if (playornot=='y')
            printf("Ok.\n");
        else (playornot=='y')
            int keep_playing=4;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your lack of braces makes it really painful to read. While loop without braces only considers first statement after the loop declaration unless you are using commas(PLEASE DO NOT USE COMMAS THOUGH). It's hard to tell what your intent is as is since the indenting is misleading. As it stands your program should be spamming you with "printf("Press 'y' to play or 'n' to quit: ");" since that's the only statement while loop sees.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I exit a while(1) based on a user input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913603/how-can-i-exit-a-while1-based-on-a-user-input)

Comment: you can use "break" to end a while loop instead of changing the value of a variable

Comment: you should use `else if (playornot=='y')`.

Comment: also, you don't require **"keep_playing"** variable for looping. You can simply use  `while (playornot == 'y')` and declare `char playornot;` outside while loop

Comment: @Dmity I normally program in python so maybe that is why. I also am new to C as I stated. I tried putting in the code of what xenteros said and it still doesn't work like I want it to after the user presses y or n. What is going on? I kinda understand but still very confused. "While loop without braces only considers first statement after the loop declaration unless you are using commas" that was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    printf("Welcome to rock paper scissors!\n");
    int keep_playing=5;
    while (keep_playing==5) {
        printf("Press 'y' to play or 'n' to quit: ");
        char playornot;
        scanf("%c",&playornot);
        if (playornot=='y') {
            printf("Ok.\n");
        } else if (playornot=='n') {
            keep_playing=4;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is how your code should look like. In your case, there was an infinite loop because the only line which was repeated was `printf("Press 'y' to play or 'n' to quit: ");`. This was caused by the luck of curly braces.

Then, you had a typo I would say - redundant `int` in `int keep_playing=4`. This declared another variable, visible only in this scope. Actually it should have caused the error when there were no curly braces, as it was the same scope at that moment.

And there was a third bug which noone mentioned before. If the entered character wasn't `y` it should have been `n`. Otherwise you should ask for another input or somehow decide how to deal with it.

And the fourth one was that yoou tried to scan two characters to `char playornot`. Removed `\n` from `scanf`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand but it is still not working like I want it to. After the user presses y for yes, it should print ok.

Comment: I did, lol. It just sits there instead of exiting or print ok.

Comment: Yes, thanks. What was different from last time?

Comment: I just wanted to know and yes I know.

Comment: I thought up votes were checking the green check mark?

Comment: Ok I think I upvoted?

Comment: @Sean.D the tick is acceptance - it's used for marking a solution. Upvoting is for marking good answers at all. I strongly recommend [ask] and [mcve] - interesting articles on how [so] works.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 basic problems:

- when using a while and you need to repeat a whole lot of lines of code you need to use braces {} around all the code that is going to be repeated.
- when you write int var you are *declaring* the variable - this tells the compiler what kind of variable it is and what it is called. Later changes to this value do not require a re-declaration as you are doing.